# Transform object into File

Tags: javascript, image, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending some File to back with no problems, but when I am trying to get this File from back I receive the following array:

```
[
{
collection_name: "question_image"
id: 35
name: "Снимок экрана 2020-03-02 в 16.52.33"
params:
collection_name: "question_image"
extension: "png"
file_name: "Снимок-экрана-2020-03-02-в-16.52.33.png"
id: 35
name: "Снимок экрана 2020-03-02 в 16.52.33"
size: 125974
type: "image/png"
__proto__: Object
thumbSquareUrl: "http://neiry.test/storage/quiz_images/35/Снимок-экрана-2020-03-02-в-16.52.33.png"
thumbUrl: "http://neiry.test/storage/quiz_images/35/conversions/Снимок-экрана-2020-03-02-в-16.52.33-thumb.jpg"
url: "http://neiry.test/storage/quiz_images/35/Снимок-экрана-2020-03-02-в-16.52.33.png"
}
]
```

I need to transform this array back into the File format for some reasons, so I'm trying to do the following:

```
let file = new File(question.image, question.image[0].name, {type:'image/png'})
```

And the file is not the same (it at least lacks the params key). What am I doing wrong and how should it be done properly?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the file using the url that is present is this response `url: "http://neiry.test/storage/quiz_images/35/Снимок-экрана-2020-03-02-в-16.52.33.png"
`

Comment: @Prakhar you mean whether I checked if this file exists or you mean I can somehow access the file via the route without actually transforming it?